# How to make regex stop at the first match?

Tags: c#, regex

String

```
<img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/><img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/><img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
```

in the string containing many or one

```
<img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
```

i try use

```
<img alt=":.*"\s?/>
```

but it takes all `/>` character in the string

string i want to get only from `<img` to first char `/>`

```
<img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
```

Comment: If you could describe what result you're getting, and what result you're hoping to get, it would help us understand your question a but more easily.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, meaning it will match all characters until before the **last** `"\s?/>` (which is pretty much the end of your example string). Solution: Make it non-greedy (also sometimes called "lazy")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will return each of the 3 img elements with the tags:

```
<\s*img[^>]*\/>
```

In order to get everything between the img tags you can use the following:

```
(?<=<\s*img)[^>]*(?=\/>)
```

In order to then get each element attribute within each tag individually you can use:

```
(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?
```

Comment: How to only get the image tag containing class `smilies` or id containing `smilie_` and the normal image tag ignored

Comment: thank you but how to get everything between the img tags only contain  `class="smilies"` or `id="smilie_`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in regex, but this breaks it up into each img tag separately. I think that's what you were going for? You can then loop through the matches. I also wrapped the internals (excluding the open and close parts of the tags) in their own group if you'd like to use it.

```
<img\s(.*?(?=\s?/>))/>
```

This results in the following matches:

```
1: <img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
2: <img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
3: <img alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"/>
```

And group 1 of each result are listed below:

```
1: alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile" 
2: alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"
3: alt=":)" class="smilies" id="smilie_207" src="https://example.com/smile.gif" title="Smile"
```

Comment: How to only get the image tag containing class `smilies` or id containing `smilie_` and the normal image tag ignored